# Is there a .NET client library for Google Smart Home Action?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am building an endpoint to fulfill Google Smart Home Actions requests. I need to build this in ASP.NET Core. Is there a library I can use to wrap Google Smart Home Actions request? I am only seeing libraries for Node.js and Java.

[Google Smart Home Actions libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKbVg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a fulfillment library for intent handling with .NET (although we are exploring the idea). However, you can use the [Google APIs for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet) client library to communicate with the [Home Graph service](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/homegraph/v1) (used for features such as Request Sync and Report State).

Here is a quick example of what the Home Graph client would look like in C#:

```cs
try
{
    // Create authorized client
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("service-account.json")
        .CreateScoped(new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph" });
    var service = new HomeGraphServiceService(
        new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "HomeGraphTester",
        });

    // Make Home Graph requests
    var request = new RequestSyncDevicesRequest{
      AgentUserId = "1234"
    };
    var response = service.Devices.RequestSync(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to look all over for one but no luck :(. I guess I will build my own and use Google APIs for .NET for Request Sync and Report State.